# append item to variable list from widget in python

Tags: python, pyside

In short what I've done is created a custom widget which contains a textEdit field. The custom widget is called FormWidget.

This custom (FormWidget) is then used multiple times inside of another widget. I was wondering how can I 'get' the value of the text field and append it a specific variable.

I don't want to directly append the variable from the FormWidget widget itself because i plan on instancing this widget multiple times and each text field will correspond to a different variable.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Info goes here...
"""

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

# Variables
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namesList = []

# custom name widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class FormWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title=None):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()
        if title!=None:
            self.listLabel.setText(title)

    def initUI(self): 

        # formatting 
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Input List")

        # widgets
        self.listLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Label")
        self.nameInput = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        # signals
        self.nameInput.returnPressed.connect(self.pressed_return)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listLabel)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.nameInput)
        self.show()

    def pressed_return(self):
        txt = self.nameInput.text()
        txt = txt.strip()
        txt = txt.replace (" ", "_")
        self.nameInput.clear()


# Main widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TeamsWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TeamsWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self): 

        # formatting 
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 50)
        self.setWindowTitle("Names")

        # widgets
        self.formWidget = FormWidget("Names")
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Print")

        # signals
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printNames)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.formWidget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.show()

    def printNames(self):
        print "Printing Names..."
        for n in namesList:
            print n


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TeamsWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You have to `append` the entry of the textbot to `namesList` as follows: `nameList.append(ENTRY_OF_THE_TEXTBOX)`

Comment: you are suggesting i place that in the custom widget though? that would be problematic since i want to use the nameWidget multiple times in the new ui. Each instance of the nameWidget will correspond to a different variable list. How do i adjust for that?

Comment: No, inside of the `printNames(self)` function. You have to append it to the list as soon as it's added (aka clicked to the button) and then print it with the look you've already done.

Comment: i understand what you are saying. I guess since im not super familiar with python, im not clear on where to place this in the code 'nameList.append(ENTRY_OF_THE_TEXTBOX)' and secondly how to actually return the 'entry of the textbox' . Would you be able to modify the code to explain how to do so more detailed please. Thank you

Comment: Try by adding this: `nameList.append(txt)` in the `pressed_return(self)` function just after `txt = txt.replace (" ", "_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the list of values in the FormWidget, storing them on returnPressed.  Then add a getValue() method to FormWidget to return the list of values.  I also added a clear() method to initialize and clear the values, this is called on init in FormWidget.

Complete code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
Info goes here...
'''

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

# Variables
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namesList = []

# custom name widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class FormWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title=None):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__()

        self.clear()

        self.initUI()
        if title!=None:
            self.listLabel.setText(title)

    def initUI(self):

        # formatting
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Input List')

        # widgets
        self.listLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Label')
        self.nameInput = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        # signals
        self.nameInput.returnPressed.connect(self.returnPressed)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listLabel)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.nameInput)
        self.show()

    def returnPressed(self):
        text = self.nameInput.text()
        text = text.strip()
        text = text.replace (' ', '_')
        self.value.append(text)
        self.nameInput.clear()

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def clear(self):
        self.value = []


# Main widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TeamsWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TeamsWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # formatting
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 50)
        self.setWindowTitle('Names')

        # widgets
        self.formWidget = FormWidget('Names')
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Print')

        # signals
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printNames)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.formWidget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.show()

    def printNames(self):
        print 'Printing Names...'
        for name in self.formWidget.getValue():
            print name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TeamsWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```